# Surge is not deploying my site

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I used `create-react-app` to make a simple playlist creator with Spotify's API. I updated my redirectUri to the surge domain: `http://jamming-1990.surge.sh/` and updated it on the dashboard of my app on Spotify's site as well.

I ran `npm run build` and followed the steps from the command `surge`, I get the output that it was created successfully but when I go to the domain, http://jamming-1990.surge.sh/ I get a 404.

Not sure what steps I missed, or why it's not deploying.

Comment: Does your site have an `index.html` file? If you're using something other than `index.html` then you'll need to add the filename to the end of the url to access it. Surge only indexes (as many web servers do) files *named* index.

Comment: It does but it might be in the wrong folder? This is what my file tree looks like:

https://imgur.com/a/3NYqmmg

Comment: There's no evidence that your site actually deployed. What's the exact output from surge?

Comment: Ok, when putting in the path, I forgot to switch to the `build` folder, which  contains the index.html file. It seems to be up now!

Answer (score 1):

When inputting the path you must make sure to be in the `build` folder instead of the main root!